# Using plumber to read json as input value of API function

Tags: r, json, api, plumber

I have a function that takes in a character vector as argument and after processing returns a result.

I want to expose it as an API using plumber. How to I pass a JSON as input

I have used the following code

```
file_recommender = function(req,res,files){

  files = as.data.frame(files)
  files = files$name
  files = as.character(files)

  library(dplyr)

  return(files)
  }
```

In the http request I am sending the data as

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_file_recommendation?files=[{"name":"pvdxmanager.h"}]

http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_file_recommendation?files={name":["pvsignmanager.cpp","pvdxmanager.cpp","pvorderoperationsmanager.h"]}
```

Comment: did you ever solve this?  I am facing the same problem at the moment ...

Answer (score 0):

I miss the reproducible example, therefore I don't know what exactly you want to do and what's your concrete problem. You don't use the `req` and `res` argument in your function and you load `dplyr` without using it. If you just want to return the file names, look at the example below.

The `plumber` part should probably look like this:

```
#* Return recommended files
#* @param files JSON containing filenames
#* @post /get_file_recommendation
file_recommender = function(files){
  files = fromJSON(files)$name
}
```

Input:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:3070/get_file_recommendation?files=%7B%22name%22%3A%22pvdxmanager.h%22%7D" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

for the following JSON:

```
{"name":"pvdxmanager.h"}
```

Response:

```
[
  "pvdxmanager.h"
]
```

Input:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:3070/get_file_recommendation?files=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22pvsignmanager.cpp%22%2C%22pvdxmanager.cpp%22%2C%22pvorderoperationsmanager.h%22%5D%7D" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

for this JSON (yours is not valid):

```
{"name":["pvsignmanager.cpp","pvdxmanager.cpp","pvorderoperationsmanager.h"]}
```

Response:

```
[
  "pvsignmanager.cpp",
  "pvdxmanager.cpp",
  "pvorderoperationsmanager.h"
]
```